# Listbox selection become textbox selection

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I want a user to be able to click a value from the listbox and have the value selected become the textbox value. I'm getting an error from `Textbox1.Value = selectedItems.Text` as a compile error: invalid qualifier for `selecteditems`. I want the value selected to appear in the textbox as well.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
Dim selectedItems As String, i As Integer
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
        selectedItems = selectedItems & ListBox1.List(i) & vbNewLine
    End If
Next i

TextBox1.Value = selectedItems.Text

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are only selecting one `ListBox` item then your current code is not right, the code in your question is used to add multiple selected items in the`ListBox1` to the current text In the textbox. You don't need to loop through each `ListBox1` item. If you want to put the clicked item from `ListBox1` into `TextBox1` you only need `TextBox1.Text = ListBox1` all the other code is excess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectedItems` is a String and strings don't have any properties such as `Text`

```
TextBox1.Value = selectedItems
```

would be what you need

Comment: Is it a multiline textbox ?  By default it will not be.

Comment: I removed my comment since I can add `myString = Left(myString, Len(myString) - 1)` to remove the paragraph sign